# Creating Array Variable or Parameters For Azure Data Factory Pipeline Using Terraform

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-azure, azure-data-factory

I am trying to create ADF pipeline using the code below. I want to pass parameter or variable type, while creating ADF pipeline. Terraform forces me to create only string variables.

In the document link below, It's written, terraform accepts the parameters as map.
Is there any way to pass parameter or variable type using terraform?

https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/azurerm/latest/docs/resources/data_factory_pipeline#variables

PS: I tried to find a trick for that like below, It didn't work.

```
resource "azurerm_data_factory_pipeline" "pl_test" {
  name                = var.name
  resource_group_name = var.resource_group_name
  data_factory_name   = var.data_factory_name
  parameters = {
            "filter_countries": "{ \"type\": \"array\", \"defaultValue\": [ \"CH\", \"DE\", \"AT\" ] }"
  }

  variables = {
            split_arr =  {
              type = "Array"
            }
        }

  activities_json = templatefile(abspath("${path.module}/templates/test_template.json"),
    {
        "test-key" = "test_param"
  })
}
```

Comment: hello @Yılmaz, as mentioned in the official site, you can pass parameters as map only . your parameter is only single variable which will not pass giving error :  "Inappropriate value for attribute "parameters": map of string required.".. for details on maps you can refer: https://www.terraform.io/docs/language/expressions/types.html#maps-objects ,,,, For more details on how to dynamically call parameters you can refer this :https://blog.johnfolberth.com/how-to-dynamically-assign-azure-policy-via-terraform/

Comment: @PrabhuDuttaMohanty thansk for the answers but it didn't work for me. the thing is azrerm is expecting value as a string not an object

Comment: yes , if you check the second link that i have provided provides an example on how to declare the parameter.. the one you are declaring is list and its not expected in parameters.

Comment: @PrabhuDuttaMohanty I checked the link, no result. I created a repository. If you wanna check it out , you can reach the the tf file here, https://github.com/ftylmz1/terraform/blob/master/azure_pipelines_with_array_parameters.tf

Comment: Indeed seems that only a string can be passed in variables. The only way I could get a "list" passed as variable was to define the elements as comma-separated string (e.g. `variables = { foovar = "aaa,bbb,ccc" }`) and then in the pipeline component requiring a list (for example ForEach) split this string like `@split(variables('foovar'), ',')`

Answer (score 0):

It appears that the provider assumes that any variables defined in the `variables` map have the `String` type.

You may use Terraform's `jsonencode` function to encode your array, e.g.

```
variables = {
  "filter_countries" = jsonencode(["CH", "DE", "AT"])
}
```

You can then use Azure Data Factory's `json` function to parse the variable, e.g.

```
@json(variables('filter_countries'))
```